# Why the original numpy array get changed while changing another array created from it?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

i have a numpy array `r` when i used to create another array `r2` out of it and turning that new array `r2` to zero it also changed the original array `r`

I have searched around the similar questions but did not turned around the any satisfying answer for this, so please consider suggesting an appropriate answer.

**Original Array:**

```
>>> r
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
```

another numpy array from original array `r2` as follows:

```
>>> r2 = r[:3, :3]
>>> r2
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [12, 13, 14]])
```

So, When i do set new array to `r2` to zero

```
>>> r2[:]  = 0
>>> r2
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

So, when i see original array then it also been looked change:

**Array Changed after chanin the new array:**

```
>>> r
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]])
```

Happy New Years in advanced, Guys!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation**

```
r2 = r[:3, :3]
```

Doesn't create a new array, but renames the current array. What you need to do is known as 'deep copy'. Use, numpy.copy() to do what you need.

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = x
z = np.copy(x)

x[0] = 10
x[0] == y[0]
True
x[0] == z[0]
False
```

Read more from,

https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html

Comment: `r2` is a new `ndarray` object, but is a `view`.  So yes you want a copy, but it doesn't need to a deep copy (that's more applicable to lists).