# Numpy array not copy

Tags: python, numpy, copy

I am working with numpy and images. I have a big image which i want to process bit by bit.
So I want to create a reference  to the original image, do something with it and move on. But when I change something in the frame the change does not transfer to the original, which is the opposite of everything I read online

for example here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53939444/11333604 if you don't use copy if you change one array the other changes. That does NOT HAPPEN to me

here is some pseudo code that demonstrates my problem

```
import numpy as np
#create a "big" imgae total black
matrix = np.full((5,5),255,np.uint8)
# the frame that i want to process 
h = 3
w = 3
sub  = matrix[:h, :w]
#mask to make everything 0 
mask = np.zeros((h,w),np.uint8)
sub = sub & mask
#also change something radom so i know the problem is not the & or the mask
sub[0][0] = 12


#sub is changes
print(sub)
#matrix is not
print(matrix)
```

output

```
[[12  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0]]
[[255 255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255 255]]
```

I suspect it has something to do with my arrays being 2d but i cant think of how

Comment: You never mutated the array being referenced by `sub`, instead, you created *a new numpy array*, `sub & mask` and assigned that to the name `sub`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in this line

```
sub = sub & mask
```

you're making `sub` to "look" at some new array formed with `sub & mask` and it loses its connection to `matrix`. If you do this in-place instead

```
sub &= mask
```

then `matrix` will be affected too:

```
>>> matrix

array([[ 12,   0,   0, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```